# Filter specific column, if matched then get the record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm on Laravel 5.2. How to filter specific column if matched the given criteria on the query?

for example I have a record like

> column[id] => '1', column[username] => 'id_45820', column[contents] =>
>   'test', column[to] => 'admin,id_45820,user', column[created_at] => '',
>   column[updated_at] => ''

and I have 2 variables as a criteria

```
$role = 'user';
$username = 'id_45820';
```

Now I want to do like filter the 'to' column using the '$role' and '$username' variable and if either the '$role' or '$username' or both is match to the contents of 'to' column (separated by comma) then pull that record, is that possible?

```
$q = notifications::where(function($query){
    //I just don't know how to do it. Help please?
})->get();
```

Comment: how is `admin,id_45820,user` stored separated by comma?

Comment: what do you mean? I don't quite get it. Its easy to store that, because the column 'to' is a variable so in my controller when saving a new record, I just have to store it a string so it consist 'roles and username' separated by commas.

Comment: @RossWilson answer is correct but `LIKE` is a very expensive operation, so I believe you should think about DB redesign.

Comment: @aleksejjj do you mean, using 'like' consumes much of the resources?

Comment: @CodeDemon Yea, this is what I meant.

Comment: @CodeDemon if you have 'joh' instead of 'john' it accepts the condition though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly then:

```
$role = 'user';
$username = 'id_45820';

$q = notifications::where(function($query) use($role, $username) {
    $query->where('to', 'like', "%{$role}%")
          ->orWhere('to', 'like', "%{$username}%");
})->get();
```

As you said you want to check if either or both exist then you just need to check if either exists.

Hope this helps!

Comment: why '%{$role}%' is different from '%{$username%}' where in '%{$username%}', the right '%' is before the '}'?

Comment: @CodeDemon ...typo. Also, with the above make sure you use `" "` rather than `' '`.

Comment: what's the meaning of the percent and curly braces please?

Comment: @CodeDemon The `%` sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after the string, so removing the first one would mean the field must start with the string and remove the second one would mean the column must end with the string. The `{}` combined with `" "`are used in place of string concatenation. In the above example you don't actually need the `{}` them but some developers always use them as it can be easier to notice what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
$q=notifications::where('to', 'like', '%' . $role . '%')
               ->orWhere('to', 'like', '%' . $user . '%')
               ->get();
```